# How do I Loop Through A Sorted Excel Range in VBA in the Order I Sorted It In?

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, filter, range

I am using VBA to sort a filtered worksheet in Excel 2010.  Visually, the sort works, but when I step through the sorted, filtered range in VBA it appears that the range is still in its original order.  For my purposes, this is not desired.

Here is an excerpt of my looping code:

```
For r = 2 To LastRow
    Set row = ws.Range(r & ":" & r)
    Debug.Print row.Row
Next
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be stepping through the [.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx) if you are on a filtered range?

Comment: Additionally to Jeeped's comment: Excel sorts only the visible rows. If you want all to be sorted then remove all filters, sort and apply the filters again.

Comment: Thank you - that worked, Jeeped.  Can you please elevate your comment to an answer so that I can credit it properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use autofilter mode=false  to clear the filter then try sorting.